# Action Script 3. How to count game time?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, time, timer, count

I'm creating Flash "memory" game, Idea to discover 2 equal cards. I need to add "Timer" in top of window which count in how many seconds all cards will be descovered.

Here is my code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import Card;
    import Boarder;
    import BlueBoard;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import RedBoard;
    import Snow;

    public class MemoryGame extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _card:Card;
        private var _boarder:Boarder;
        private var _blueBoard:BlueBoard;
        private var _cardX:Number;
        private var _cardY:Number;
        private var _firstCard:*;
        private var _totalMatches:Number;
        private var _currentMatches:Number;
        private var _redBoard:RedBoard;
        private var _snow:Snow;
        private var _cards:Array;
        public var  _message:String;

        public function MemoryGame()
        {
            _cards = new Array();
            _totalMatches = 4;
            _currentMatches = 0;
            createCards();
        }

        private function createCards():void
        {
            _cardX = 45;
            _cardY = 10;

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _boarder = new Boarder();
                _card.setType(_boarder);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 50;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            for(var j:Number = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _blueBoard = new BlueBoard();
                _card.setType(_blueBoard);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 50;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            _cardX = 45;
            _cardY = _card.height + 30;

            for(var k:Number = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _redBoard = new RedBoard();
                _card.setType(_redBoard);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 50;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            for(var l:Number = 0; l < 2; l++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _snow = new Snow();
                _card.setType(_snow);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 50;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            randomizeCards(_cards);
        }

        private function checkCards(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);

            if(_firstCard == undefined)
            {
                _firstCard = event.currentTarget;
            }
            else if(String(_firstCard._type) == String(event.currentTarget._type))
            {
                trace("match");
                _message = "match";
                message_txt.text = _message;
                _firstCard = undefined;
                _currentMatches ++;
                if(_currentMatches >= _totalMatches)
                {
                    trace("YOU WIN !!!");
                    _message = "YOU WIN !!!";
                    message_txt.text = _message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                trace("wrong");
                _message = "wrong";
                message_txt.text = _message;
                _firstCard.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
                event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
                _firstCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                event.currentTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _firstCard = undefined;             
            }
        }

        private function randomizeCards(cards:Array):void
        {
            var randomCard1:Number;
            var randomCard2:Number;
            var card1X:Number;
            var card1Y:Number;

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                randomCard1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
                randomCard2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);

                card1X = cards[randomCard1].x;
                card1Y = cards[randomCard1].y;
                cards[randomCard1].x = cards[randomCard2].x;
                cards[randomCard1].y = cards[randomCard2].y
                cards[randomCard2].x = card1X;
                cards[randomCard2].y = card1Y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
And I have one more question. When I will add this game to PHP, how can I add username and his time to database? I need write code in Action Script (swf file) or I can do it in php later? I mean in php can I use any method to get time from swf file and write it to database?

Could you help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use the `Timer` class (flash.utils.Timer) to accomplished what you're asking:

```
    var timer:Timer; //import flash.utils.Timer;
    var txtTime:TextField;
    var tmpTime:Number;  //this will store the time when the game is started    

//your constructor:
public function MemoryGame()
{
    timer = new Timer(1000); //create a new timer that ticks every second.
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick, false, 0, true); //listen for the timer tick

    txtTime = new TextField();
    addChild(txtTime);

    tmpTime = flash.utils.getTimer();
    timer.start(); //start the timer
    //....the rest of your code
}

private function tick(e:Event):void {
    txtTime.text = showTimePassed(flash.utils.getTimer() - tmpTime);
}

//this function will format your time like a stopwatch
function showTimePassed(startTime:int):String {
  var leadingZeroMS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the miliseconds
  var leadingZeroS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the seconds

  var time = getTimer() - startTime; //this gets the amount of miliseconds elapsed
  var miliseconds = (time % 1000); // modulus (%) gives you the remainder after dividing, 


  if (miliseconds < 10) { //if less than two digits, add a leading 0
    leadingZeroMS = "0";
  }

  var seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60); //this gets the amount of seconds

  if (seconds < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
    leadingZeroS = "0";
  }

  var minutes = Math.floor( (time / (60 * 1000) ) ); //60 seconds times 1000 miliseocnds gets the minutes
  return minutes + ":" + leadingZeroS + seconds + "." + leadingZeroMS + miliseconds;
}


//in your you-win block of code:
var score = flash.utils.getTimer() - tmpTime; //this store how many milliseconds it took them to complete the game.
```

This creates a timer that will tick every second, and update a text field with the current amount of seconds elapsed

---

As per the second part of your request, here is a way you can do this (the database work needs to be done in PHP, this shows you how to send the data to a php page)

```
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scoreSaveResponse,false,0,true);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mysite.com/score.php");
        var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            urlVars.time = flash.utils.getTimer() - tmpTime;
            urlVars.userName = "yourUserName";
            //add any other parameters you want to pass to your PHP page
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        urlLoader.data = urlVars;
        urlLoader.load(request);

function scoreSaveResponse(e:Event):void {
    //whatever you return from the php page is found in urlLoader.data
}
```

Comment: Timer is probably not such a great idea, because the actual duration of each tick is subjected to a lot of variables that will make it off-time. For exact time you might want to use `flash.utils.getTimer`.

Comment: Thank you, timer works. Hard to make timer MM:SS? I mean after 60 seconds that timer will show 1minute. And about second question I really misunderstood, could you explain me a little bit more?

Comment: @MartyWallace - if you need an exact time down to the millisecond then getTimer would be more accurate yes. You'll need the timer anyway though to update the text field and for simplicity on the concept I just left it at that.

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė - I added some updates. THe second part shows how you send data from AS3 to a PHP (or any) web page.  It's up to the PHP page to decide what to do with the data it recieves.